# Не работают WiFi Lock и Wake Lock

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, которое скачивает аудиофайлы по сети и воспроизводит их на Android устройстве. Мне нужно, чтобы устройство «не засыпало» при воспроизведении музыки. Для этого использую WiFi Lock и Wake Lock в классе `Application`, производном от `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(wifiManager != null) {
            _wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "music player lock");
            _wifiLock.acquire();
        }
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (mgr != null) {
            _wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "music player lock");
            _wakeLock.acquire();
        }
        ...
    }
```

Проверяю в `adb shell dumpsys`:

> Wake Locks: size=1   PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'music player 
>   lock' (uid=10085, pid=3179, ws=null)
>
> ...
>
> Locks held:
>   WifiLock{music player lock type=3 uid=10085}

Однако звук через некоторое время после нажатия кнопки питания все равно отключается. Если потом снова её нажать, то почти сразу же воспроизведение продолжается. В чём может быть причина и как это исправить? На тестируемом устройстве cистема Android 7.0.